# NodeJs project how to make user input in a form unsanitized?

Tags: node.js

I have a form in a NodeJs project where I am using:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

I want to make it where if a user enters `<h1>hello</h1>` into the form that it will show up as "hello" formatted as an h1 instead of `<h1>hello</h1>`

```
<form action="/blogs" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="image" placeholder="image url">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" placeholder="description">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
        Submit
        </button>
    </div>  
</form>
```

Comment: Where should it be displayed ? In the console ? In an html page ?

Comment: In an HTML page. Right now when I type <h1>hello</h1> into the form and submit it it renders as "<h1>hello</h1>" as a string instead of actually recognizing that it is html.

Comment: can you show your html code ?

Comment: I edited the original post to show the HTML

Comment: where is your input displayed ?

Comment: You only included the input part. The cause of the issue might be at the output stage, please also include how you output the html from the user.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. 
In Node.js if you want to display information as HTML, in the index.ejs file
you need to do a 
    <%- blog.description %>
, where that dash is the key. 
Before i had 
    <%= blog.description %>.